# Symfony login form redirect according to user role

Tags: symfony, security, authentication, user-roles

I've used the maker bundle to create a standard login form. When the user has successfully logged in it calls function onAuthenticationSuccess to redirect to the new page.

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {         
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_homepage'));      
    }
```

However, I would like to redirect to different pages depending on what role the user has. I would like to do something like:

```
if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_STANDARD_USER')) {
    return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_homepage')); 
}

if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_SYS_ADMIN')) {
    return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_ADMINpage')); 
}
```

But the error I'm getting is Undefined property: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator::$security

Many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Where are you defining `$security`? Which version of Symfony are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have much to go by, but it seems that [the default implementation of the LoginFormAuthenticator](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/blob/master/src/Resources/skeleton/authenticator/LoginFormAuthenticator.tpl.php) does not request the [AuthorizationChecker](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html#authorization-checker).

You can fix this by injecting an AuthorizationChecker into your class using the constructor. [Example of how dependency injection works](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#injecting-services-config-into-a-service)

Seeing as you have used the maker bundle, it is safe to assume you have [autowiring turned on](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html) for your services, meaning that the Symfony kernel will automagically do all the rest of the work